# ld: library not found when calling go function from Rust

Tags: c, go, rust, linker, shared-libraries

I want to call a go function from Rust trough a shared c library but running into a library linker issue.

Here is my code:

1. hello.go

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "C"

//export Hello
func Hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello Go C-Shared")
}

func main() {}
```

`go build -o Hello.so -buildmode=c-shared hello.go`

outputs the `Hello.h` file and `Hello.so` file.

2. Next I created a rust-hello-world project, and I moved `Hello.h` and `Hello.so` file to the same directory `src` of main.rs, and invoked the external Hello function in main.rs.

```
#[link(name = "Hello")]
extern "C" {
    fn Hello();
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {Hello()};
}
```

3. I did some research and tried the following environment variables before `cargo build`

- `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/dev/rust-hello-world/src/`
- `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/dev/rust-hello-world/src/Hello.so`
- `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/dev/rust-hello-world/src/`
- `export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:~/dev/rust-hello-world/src/`

But all of them generated the same error

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="..."
  = note: ld: library not found for -lHello
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Version info:

`cargo 1.69.0-nightly (9d5b32f50 2023-02-22)`

`go version go1.19 darwin/amd64`

`os version: MacOS Ventura 13.1 (22C65)`

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: If you create `Hello.so`, then `-lHello` will _not_ find it. You need to create `libHello.so`. If the path to `libHello.so` is (e.g.) `/foo/bar/libHello.so`, you need: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/foo/bar`. Or, instead of `-lHello`, you would need: `/foo/bar/Hello.so`

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks. I used `go build -o libHello.so -buildmode=c-shared hello.go` this time, and followed your suggestion to export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH using the absolute path, but still got the same error. I also tried to use the link name "libHello" although I believe it should be "Hello". Do you have any further suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These steps worked for my case.
Build the library:

`go build -o libHello.so -buildmode=c-shared hello.go`

Link to the library:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/absolute/path/to/the/library

RUSTFLAGS="/absolute/path/to/the/library" cargo build
```

I removed the `-lstatic` from @cafce25's answer when setting `RUSTFLAGS` as it requires a libHello.a file. Since I have built the libHello.so library with Go instead of Rust, in this case, I won't be able to find a libHello.a file because it is a static library file specific to Rust.

`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are environment variables used by dynamic linkers to search for shared libraries (aka dynamic link libraries).

`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used on macOS, while `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used on Linux/Unix systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can link a shared object that you created like this:

```bash
go build -o libhello.so --buildmode=c-shared hello.go
```

and then telling `cargo` to use the proper directory to search for your library file and the library to include:

```bash
RUSTFLAGS="-Lnative=/absolute/path/to/your/library -lstatic=hello" cargo build
```

and at runtime you have to include the shared object in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/absolute/path/to/your/library target/debug/your_crate_name
```